# Not getting data in my recycler view

Tags: android

I am unable to get data in my recycler view.I am very new to android and trying to implement this recycler view in tablayout but not getting any data .There are three tab and trying this code with one tab.Please help me out with this.Thanks in advance.

My code is below.

I have created two xml file one for recyler view and another one for custom rows.
Below here is my activity code.

My Fragment Activity

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private vivzadapter adapter;
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView)layout.findViewById(R.id.lis);
        adapter = new vivzadapter(getActivity(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return layout;
    }
public static List<Information> getData(){
    List<Information> data =new ArrayList<>();
    int icons=(R.drawable.icon);
    String[] titles = {"Ashish", "shivam", "yogesh", "ravi"};
    for (int i=0;i<titles.length;i++) {
        Information information = new Information();
        information.iconId=icons;
        information.title=titles[i];
        data.add(information);
    }
    return data;
}
}
```

My Adapter Activity-

```
public class vivzadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<vivzadapter.MyViewHolder>{
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Information> data= Collections.emptyList();
    public vivzadapter(Context context,List<Information> data){
       inflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);
       this.data = data;
   }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view=   inflater.inflate(R.layout.customrow, parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder= new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Information current = data.get(position);
holder.title.setText(current.title);
holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
TextView title;
ImageView icon;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textvw);
            icon =(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

to:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```